# Error: value out-of-bounds on callbackGasLimit variable

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

i have written a simple contract in solidity as seen below

```
/**
 * @title Lottery
 * @notice Enter lottery by paying some amount
 * @notice pick a random number( verifiably random)
 * @notice winner be selected every xtimes
 */

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";

// ============= Errors ====================
error Lottery__NotEnoughFunds();
error Lottery__TransferFailed();
error Lottery__NotOpen();
error Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 raffleState);


contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    //  ============= Type declaration ===========
    enum LotteryState {
        OPEN, 
        CALCULATING
    }
    // ======== state variables ============
    uint256 private immutable i_entranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATION = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;

    address private s_recentwinner;
    LotteryState private s_lotteryState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
   

    // ========== Events ==================
    event LotteryEnter(address indexed player);
    event RandomwinnerRequest(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);


    // ========= constructor ============
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint256 entranceFee,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_entranceFee = entranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        i_interval = interval;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    }

    //   ========== functions ============
    function enterLottery() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_entranceFee) {
            revert Lottery__NotEnoughFunds();
        }
        if (s_lotteryState != LotteryState.OPEN ) {
            revert Lottery__NotOpen();
        }

        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        emit LotteryEnter(msg.sender);
    }

   
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = LotteryState.OPEN == s_lotteryState;
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = s_players.length > 0;
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers);
        // return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0"); // can we comment this out?
    }

    function performUpkeep( bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {

        ( bool upKeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");

        if(!upKeepNeeded){
             revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_lotteryState)
            );
        }
        //  Request a random number
        // Once we get it , do something with it
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.CALCULATING;
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATION,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RandomwinnerRequest(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 /*requestId*/, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        // Modulo function
        uint256 winnerIndex = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[winnerIndex];
        s_recentwinner = recentWinner;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        if (!success) {
            revert Lottery__TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    // =============== View /Pure functions =============
    function getEntraceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_entranceFee;
    }

    function getPlayers(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentwinner;
    }
     function getRaffleState() public view returns (LotteryState) {
        return s_lotteryState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATION;
    }
    function getLastTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }
}
```

and it deploy script

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
  VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");

const VR_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("4");

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId;

  if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address;
    const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription();
    const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
    subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
    // fund the subscription
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VR_FUND_AMOUNT);
  } else {
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"];
    subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"];
  }

  const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"];
  const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"];
  const callbackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"];
  const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"];
  const args = [
    vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
    entranceFee,
    gasLane,
    subscriptionId,
    callbackGasLimit,
    interval,
  ];
  const lottery = await deploy("Lottery", {
    from: deployer,
    args: args,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
  });

  if (
    !developmentChains.includes(network.name) &&
    process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  ) {
    log("Verifying.....");
    await verify(lottery.address, args);
  }
  log("-----------------------------------");
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "lottery"];
```

mock deploy script

```
const { network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")


const BASE_FEE = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25") // 0.25 is this the premium in LINK?
const GAS_PRICE_LINK = 1e9 // link per gas, is this the gas lane? // 0.000000001 LINK per gas

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments })  {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    const args =[BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK]
    // If we are on a local development network, we need to deploy mocks!

    if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)){
        log("Local Network Detected! Deploying mocks...")
        // deploy a mock vrfCoordinator
        await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",{
            from:deployer,
            log:true,
            args:args,
        })
        log("Mocks Deployed!")
        log("------------------------------------------")
    }
    
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

and helper  configuration

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

const networkConfig = {
    5:{
        name:"goerli",
        vrfCoordinatorV2:"0x2Ca8E0C643bDe4C2E08ab1fA0da3401AdAD7734D",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane:"0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
        subscriptionId:"0",
        callbackGasLimit:"500000",
        interval:"30"
    },
    31337:{
        name:"hardhat",
        entranceFee: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
        gasLane:"0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15",
        callbackGasLimit:"500000",
        interval:"30"
    }
}

const developmentChains = ["hardhat", "localhost"]
module.exports = {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains
}
```

when run yarn hardhat deploy, i encounter an error
as below

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: ERROR processing C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\deploy\01-deploy-lottery.js:
Error: value out-of-bounds (argument="callbackGasLimit", value="0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
    at NumberCoder.Coder._throwError (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\abstract-coder.ts:68:16)
    at NumberCoder.encode (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\number.ts:35:18)
    at C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:71:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:54:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\tuple.ts:54:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\abi-coder.ts:111:15)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\amoko\Desktop\blockchain\lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:584:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

i need help on figuring out why is it is propagting this error and how to fix it

I have tried changing the callbackgasLimit but it still brings the error. i expect the contract to get deployed on my localhost network when i run yarn hardhat deploy

Answer (score 0):

i discovered that i had used a wrong variable(raffleState) in defining the event "Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded" so it was leading to a significant increase in gas fees which were exceeding the max gas limit set for the testnet hence the error